# Error installing Theme on GoDaddy Drupal 8.4.5

Tags: 8

I have goDaddy and installed [Drupal 8.4.5](https://www.drupal.org/8), the newest version they have on their Installation. Trying to install the theme Nexus, when I upload the theme from archive (zip file) and click install I get the following error.

> The website encountered an unexpected error. please try again later.

I have tried clearing the cache. I was running [Drupal 8.3.2](https://www.drupal.org/8) and it would just go to a blank screen; updating to Drupal 8.4.5 now got me to this error. I have downloaded and tried about 20 different themes. I either get this error or I get that the file is over 2 megabyte and is too big. What am I doing wrong or how do I fix this error?

Comment: Seems two things got mixed up here. Could you please totally disregard the theme problem for now and get your site first properly updated to 8.4.5? If you succeed to get it running without errors after the update then only deal with theme task.

Comment: it was successfully updated to 8.4.5. I got the theme fixed. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Based on the two errors you noted:

- "The website encountered an unexpected error. please try again later."
- the file is over 2mb

It sounds like your web-hosting provider/CPanel account has a limit on file uploads set, and:

a) your Drupal Core update/upgrade wasn't completed successfully

b) you may not have a temporary directory configured properly for unzipping the theme archive.

---

Recommended course of action would be to:

1. finish your Drupal 8.4.5 upgrade (or perform a fresh install on GoDaddy).  If you're drupal core codebase was updated, be sure to go to update.php to ensure all Drupal database updates were applied.
2. Once Drupal Core has been updated and you can navigate the site/add test content successfully, unzip the theme codebase locally and upload the "nexus" folder to your Drupal site's /themes/custom/ folder using either GoDaddy's file manager, ftp, or via version control tools such as *git*.
3. With the theme folder manually installed to the server, flush the cache of your Drupal site; go to Appearance, select and enable the Nexus theme.

Comment: So I uninstalled and re-installed. Now I have Drupal 8.5, however there is no longer an install theme button. How do I get this back?

Comment: If I can't get it back and have to do it manually, like you suggested, do I upload the files that I downloaded that end in the .yml to the /custom/ folder

Comment: GOT IT! Thank you! I uninstalled it 3 times before and it didn't work, this time it updated to 8.5 and I think that fixed it. Greatly appreciate it.